# Как получить доступ к приватному члену класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, задание-на-собеседовании

На [сайте с вопросами с интервью](https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/interview-questions) есть следующий вопрос:

```cpp
class Something {
public:
    Something() {
        topSecretValue = 42;
    }
    bool somePublicBool;
    int somePublicInt;
    std::string somePublicString;
private:
    int topSecretValue;
};
```

Необходимо [не трогая исходный класс] получить значение `topSecretValue`. И приводится решение:

```cpp
class SomethingReplica {
public:
    int getTopSecretValue() { return topSecretValue; }
    bool somePublicBool;
    int somePublicInt;
    std::string somePublicString;
private:
    int topSecretValue;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Something a;
    SomethingReplica* b = reinterpret_cast<SomethingReplica*>(&a);
    std::cout << b->getTopSecretValue();
}
```

Мой вопрос в том, является ли такое решение валидным? Разве мы можем кастить к произвольным классам? И если нет, то есть ли у этого вопроса валидное решение?

Comment: Как минимум решение интересное, для меня даже неожиданное, и я не вижу тут ничего не ООП-шного, хотя безусловно такое решение является хаком, но все же любой кастинг либо отнимает какие-то возможности (полиморфизм не обязывает к полному совпадению, достаточно совпадения по некоторому интерфейсу), либо может их дать, что мы тут и наблюдаем.

Comment: Решение не валидное, при разыменовании полученного указателя поведение не определено.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**№0: Дратути**

Используется отсутствие проверки доступа при инстанцировании шаблона.

```
template<typename x_Ptr>
struct Get
{
    static inline x_Ptr ptr;
};

template<auto x_ptr>
struct Access
{
    static inline int dummy{(Get<decltype(x_ptr)>::ptr = x_ptr, 0)};
};

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// класс без изменений!
class Something {
public:
    Something() {
        topSecretValue = 42;
    }
    bool somePublicBool;
    int somePublicInt;
    std::string somePublicString;
private:
    int topSecretValue;
};

template struct Access<&Something::topSecretValue>;

int main()
{
    Something something{};
    ::std::cout << something.*(Get<int Something::*>::ptr);
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:16,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:16,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:16,selectionStartLineNumber:29,startColumn:16,startLineNumber:29),source:%27template%3Ctypename+x_Ptr%3E%0Astruct+Get%0A%7B%0A++++static+inline+x_Ptr+ptr%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cauto+x_ptr%3E%0Astruct+Access%0A%7B%0A++++static+inline+int+dummy%7B(Get%3Cdecltype(x_ptr)%3E::ptr+%3D+x_ptr,+0)%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0A//+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9!!%0Aclass+Something+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Something()+%7B%0A++++++++topSecretValue+%3D+42%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++bool+somePublicBool%3B%0A++++int+somePublicInt%3B%0A++++std::string+somePublicString%3B%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+topSecretValue%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+struct+Access%3C%26Something::topSecretValue%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Something+something%7B%7D%3B%0A++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+something.*(Get%3Cint+Something::*%3E::ptr)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.28519099947672,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.71480900052329,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g131,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.71480900052329,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Можете подробней объяснить последнюю строчку, как мы у Something вызываем Get? И почему там указатель на член?

Comment: @ramzan Мы не вызываем `Get` у `Something`. Мы разыменовывавем указатель `Get<int Something::*>::ptr`, в котором хранится значение указателя на `Something::topSecretValue`, тем самым легально получая значение `topSecretValue`.

Comment: А обязательно dummy делать или можно куда-то decltype засунуть попроще? Т.е. почему просто `Get<decltype(x_ptr)>::ptr = x_ptr` нельзя?

Comment: @ramzan Смысл `dummy` в том, что мы при инстанцировании `Access<&Something::topSecretValue>` сохраняем значение адреса `Something::topSecretValue` в  `Get<int Something::*>::ptr`. Мы же не можем просто писать  произвольные выражения где угодно, поэтому присваивание происходит при инициализации `dummy`.

Comment: @user7860670 очень интересный подход. А как реализовать подобное для закрытых методов и статических закрытых? Дайте референт...

Comment: @badcast Да точно так же, при инстанцировании просто передавайте нужный указатель.

Comment: @user7860670 пните меня на ресурсы/книги к такому не стандартному (как мне кажется) коду. 
Вы меня удивили. Хочу знать больше, чем имею.

Comment: @badcast Мне кажется это я подсмотрел где-то в обсуждениях к стандарту. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/

Answer (score 5):

Вот, из [Саттера](https://psv4.userapi.com/c538210/u10903696/docs/ea986af4ceca/Satter_G_-_Novye_slozhnye_zadachi_na_S__C__In.pdf) — всевозможные на тот момент С++03 способы :)

Рассмотрим следующий заголовочный файл.

```
// Файл x.h 
// 
class X { 
public:
    X() : private_(1) { /*...*/ }
    template<class T>
    void f( const T& t ) { /*...*/ }
    int Value() { return private_; }
    // ...
private: 
    int private_; 
};
```

Покажите, как произвольный вызывающий код может получить непосредственный доступ к закрытому члену класса `private_`.

**Преступник №1: фальсификатор**

Метод фальсификатора состоит в том, чтобы продублировать определение фальсифицируемого класса, в которое внесены все необходимые нам изменения, например:

```
// Пример 15-1: ложь и подделка
//
class X {
    // Вместо включения файла x.h, вручную (и незаконно)
    // дублируем определение X и добавляем строку наподобие
    // этой: 
    friend ::Hijack( X& );
};
void Hijack( X& x ) {
    x.private_ = 2;      // Злобный смех
}
```

Конечно, то, что сделано, — не законно. Это не законно хотя бы потому, что нарушает правило одного определения, которое гласит, что если тип (в нашем случае — `X`) определен более одного раза, то все его определения должны быть идентичны. Используемый же в приведенном примере объект хотя и называется `X` и выглядит похожим на `X`, но это не тот же `X`, который используется остальным кодом программы. Тем не менее, такой “хак” будет работать на большинстве компиляторов, поскольку расположение данных объекта останется неизменным.

**Преступник №2: карманник**

Карманник сработает тихо — подменив смысл определения класса, например, следующим образом.

```
// Пример 15-2: использование макромагии
//
#define private public        // Не законно!
#include "x.h"
void Hijack( X& x ) {
    x.private_ = 2;           // Злобный смех
}
```

Этот человек — карманник. Запомните его умелые пальцы!
Конечно, то, что делает карманник, — не законно. Код из примера 15-2 непереносим по двум причинам.
   Не законно переопределять при помощи директивы `#define` зарезервированные слова.
   При этом происходит такое же нарушение правила одного определения, как и у фальсификатора. Однако если расположение данных объекта остается неизменным, этот способ сработает.

**Преступник №3: мошенник**

Принцип работы мошенника — в подмене понятий.

```
// Пример 15-3: попытка имитации размещения данных объекта
//
class BaitAndSwitch {// В надежде, что размещение данных в
public:              // этом классе будет тем же, что и в X
    int notSoPrivate;
};
void f( X& x ) {
    (reinterpret_cast<BaitAndSwitch&>(x)).notSoPrivate = 2;
}                                           // Злобный смех
```

Этот человек — мошенник. Хорошенько его запомните! Его реклама рассчитана только на то, чтоб затащить вас в магазин, а уж там он обязательно ухитриться продать вам совершенно не ту вещь, о которой шла речь в рекламе, да еще и в несколько раз дороже, чем в любом другом месте.

Конечно, то, что делает мошенник, — не законно. Код из примера 15-3 не законен по двум причинам.
   Нет гарантии, что размещение объектов `X` и `BaitAndSwitch` в памяти будет одинаковым — хотя на практике это обычно так и есть.
   Результат `reinterpret_cast` не определен, хотя большинство компиляторов сделают именно то, чего от них хочет мошенник. В конце концов, говоря волшебное слово `reinterpret_cast`, вы заставляете компилятор поверить вам и закрыть глаза на подготавливаемое вами мошенничество.

**Персона грата №4: адвокат**

Многие из нас недаром больше боятся хорошо одетых и улыбающихся адвокатов, чем (других) преступников.
Рассмотрим следующий код.

```
// Пример 15-4: проныра-законник
//
namespace {
    struct Y {};
}
template<>
void X::f( const Y& ) {
    private_ = 2;               // Злобный смех
}
void Test() {
    X x;
    cout << x.Value() << endl;  // Выводит 1
    x.f( Y() );
    cout << x.Value() << endl;  // Выводит 2
}
```

Этот человек — адвокат, который знает все лазейки. Его невозможно поймать, поскольку он слишком осторожен, чтобы нарушить букву закона, при этом нарушая его дух. Запомните и избегайте таких неджентльменов.
Как бы мне ни хотелось сказать “Конечно, то, что делает адвокат, — не законно”, увы, я не могу этого сделать, поскольку все сделанное в последнем примере законно. Почему? В примере 15-4 использован тот факт, что у `X` есть шаблон функции-члена. Приведенный код соответствует стандарту, так что последний гарантирует, что он будет работать так, как ожидается.

Comment: Но у нас же нет такой шаблонной функции

Answer (score 3):

Мы в продакшене (только тсс!) делаем примерно вот так.

Это похоже на ответ @user7860670, но работает полностью во время компиляции (можно использовать в `constexpr`-выражениях), и не плодит лишних переменных в рантайме.

Использование:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int a;

  public:
    constexpr A(int a) : a(a) {}
};

template struct RegisterMember<"my_a", &A::a>;

int main()
{
    A a(42);
    std::cout << GetMember<"my_a">(a) << '\n';
}
```

Реализация:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>

template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstString
{
    char value[N]{};

    constexpr ConstString() {}
    constexpr ConstString(const char (&source)[N])
    {
        std::copy_n(source, N, value);
    }
};

namespace // To avoid ODR violations for duplicate keys.
{
    namespace detail::PrivateAccess
    {
        [[maybe_unused]] constexpr void _adl_GetMember() {} // Dummy ADL target.

        template <ConstString Key>
        struct Reader
        {
            #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
            #pragma GCC diagnostic push
            #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
            #endif
            friend constexpr auto _adl_GetMember(Reader<Key>);
            #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
            #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
            #endif
        };

        template <ConstString Key, auto Value>
        struct Writer
        {
            friend constexpr auto _adl_GetMember(Reader<Key>)
            {
                return Value;
            }
        };
    }

    template <ConstString Key, typename T, typename ...P>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr decltype(auto) GetMember(T &&target, P &&... params)
    {
        using detail::PrivateAccess::_adl_GetMember;
        return std::invoke(_adl_GetMember(detail::PrivateAccess::Reader<Key>{}), std::forward<T>(target), std::forward<P>(params)...);
    }
}

template <ConstString Key, auto Value>
struct RegisterMember : detail::PrivateAccess::Writer<Key, Value> {};
```